# Regular Expression for changing other languages' numbers to English numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode

I want to check if a number is Arabic , and replace all it's digits to English so that I can do calculation on it . I'm trying this Function , but I don't know what regular expression is suitable for it :

```
function enNumber(num)
{
for (var i=0;i<10;i++)
num=num.replace(*[regular expression]*,i);
return num;}
```

Comment: you can try `[^/w]`  this will replace anything  which is not a letter, number or underscore.

Comment: No need to jump on regular expressions. Just ask about the task which is *really* needed. If regular expressions are used, then so be it: but don't don a box and sit in an imaginary corner ..

Comment: the task is sending this number to a php function using Ajax . that function only accepts english numbers .and the number is an input from a form .

Comment: diEcho @ why should I do that exactly ?

Comment: @user1585033 diEcho must have misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Minimum solution for the question that was asked

This should solve what you asked for:

```
function fromArabicToASCII(arabic) {
  return arabic.replace(
    /[\u0660-\u0669\u06F0-\u06F9]/g,
    function(a) {
      return String.fromCharCode((a.charCodeAt(0)&15)+48);
    }
  );
};
```

## General function for all known digits in Unicode class Nd (Number, Decimal Digit)

The function below has support for Unicode class Nd (Number, Decimal Digit):
*Adlam, Ahom, Arabic-indic, Balinese, Bengali, Bhaiksuki, Brahmi, Chakma, Cham, Devanagari, Extended Arabic-indic, Fullwidth, Gujarati, Gurmukhi, Javanese, Kannada, Kayah Li, Khmer, Khudawadi, Lao, Lepcha, Limbu, Malayalam, Mathematical Bold, Mathematical Double-struck, Mathematical Monospace, Mathematical Sans-serif Bold, Mathematical Sans-serif, Meetei Mayek, Modi, Mongolian, Mro, Myanmar Shan, Myanmar Tai Laing, Myanmar, New Tai Lue, Newa, Nko, Ol Chiki, Oriya, Osmanya, Pahawh Hmong, Saurashtra, Sharada, Sinhala Lith, Sora Sompeng, Sundanese, Tai Tham Hora, Tai Tham Tham, Takri, Tamil, Telugu, Thai, Tibetan, Tirhuta, Vai, Warang Citi.*

There is no support for roman numbers and other non-decimal numbers, because they are not decimal.

```
// This function takes an UTF16 encoded string as input,
// and returns with all suported digits from Unicode
// class 'Nd' (Number, Decimal Digit) replaced with their
// equivalent ASCII digit.
// Source : http://stackoverflow.com/a/12171250/36866
// License: MIT
// Author : some@domain.name
// Note   : If you are going to use this code I would appreciate to
//          get an email to some@domain.name. You don't have to but
//          it would make me happier!
var digitsToASCII=
  (function () {
    // Regexp that matches all supported digits.
    // Most Unicode digit classes have the zero digit at a codepoint
    // where the four least significant bits are ether zero or six.
    // The notable exception is the Math-class where several classes
    // have sequential codepoints. The information about the offset
    // is needed when decoding, and by using groups in the RexExp
    // no lookup is needed.
    var reDigit = new RegExp(
      '('+ // Offset 0
        '['+
          '\u0030-\u0039\u0660-\u0669\u06F0-\u06F9\u07C0-\u07C9'+
          '\u0E50-\u0E59\u0ED0-\u0ED9\u0F20-\u0F29\u1040-\u1049'+
          '\u1090-\u1099\u17E0-\u17E9\u1810-\u1819\u19D0-\u19D9'+
          '\u1A80-\u1A89\u1A90-\u1A99\u1B50-\u1B59\u1BB0-\u1BB9'+
          '\u1C40-\u1C49\u1C50-\u1C59\uA620-\uA629\uA8D0-\uA8D9'+
          '\uA900-\uA909\uA9D0-\uA9D9\uA9F0-\uA9F9\uAA50-\uAA59'+
          '\uABF0-\uABF9\uFF10-\uFF19'+
        ']'+
        '|\uD801[\uDCA0-\uDCA9]'+
        '|\uD804[\uDCF0-\uDCF9\uDDD0-\uDDD9\uDEF0-\uDEF9]'+
        '|\uD805['+
          '\uDC50-\uDC59\uDCD0-\uDCD9\uDE50-\uDE59'+
          '\uDEC0-\uDEC9\uDF30-\uDF39'+
        ']'+
        '|\uD806[\uDCE0-\uDCE9]|\uD807[\uDC50-\uDC59]'+
        '|\uD81A[\uDE60-\uDE69]|\uD81A[\uDF50-\uDF59]'+
        '|\uD83A[\uDD50-\uDD59]'+
      ')|('+ // Offset 6
        '['+
          '\u0966-\u096F\u09E6-\u09EF\u0A66-\u0A6F\u0AE6-\u0AEF'+
          '\u0B66-\u0B6F\u0BE6-\u0BEF\u0C66-\u0C6F\u0CE6-\u0CEF'+
          '\u0D66-\u0D6F\u0DE6-\u0DEF\u1946-\u194F'+
        ']'+
        '|\uD804[\uDC66-\uDC6F\uDD36-\uDD3F]'+
      ')|('+ // Math
        '\uD835[\uDFCE-\uDFFF]'+
      ')',
      'g'
    );

    function replace(match, offset0, offset6, offsetMath) {
      // 'match' contains the whole match and can therefore have
      // a length longer than one character if surrogate pairs is used.
      // By getting the last character from 'match' the operation is simplified.
      var raw = match.charCodeAt( match.length - 1);
      var digit =
        offset0 ? raw & 0xF : // use 4 bits
        offset6 ? (raw -6) & 0xF : // subtract 6, use 4 bits
        offsetMath ? ((raw - 0xCE) & 0x3F) % 10 : // subtract CE, use 6 bits
        null;

      return String.fromCharCode(48 + digit); // Digit to ASCII
    }

    return function replaceDigits(input) {
      return input.replace(reDigit, replace);
    }
  })();
```

Usage:

```
myAsciiVariable = digitsToASCII( myForeignVariable );
```

## Module for node.js

A function similar to this one is now available in a node.js module called `unicodedigits`. That function can translate from any supported digit to ASCII or any of the supported ranges.

You can install it with `npm install unicodedigits --save` or find it on [github.com/somec/unicodedigits](https://github.com/somec/unicodedigits)

Comment: You said arabic, but didn't say what codepoints. Are you maybe using EXTENDED ARABIC-INDIC \u06f0-\u06f9 ?

Comment: @user1585033, to change the content of the variable containing the number, you need to assign the result of the function to it.

Comment: @Some, numbers are in fact entered in a form by user , and I think numbers entered by keyboard in Arabic must be from u+0660 to u+0669 .
JukkaK.Korpela,it is what I do already.

Comment: @user1585033 If the above function with support for multiple numbers doesn't help, I don't know what will.

Comment: Thank you so much!  the second function works , you are my hero ;)

Comment: @user1585033 Great! If the first function didn't solve your problem but the second did, then your your numbers isn't in the range u0660-u0669. If you put one of the foreign numbers into a string variabel called `foreignNumber' and then do `alert(foreignNumber.charCodeAt(0).toString(16));` you can see what number it is, and you can modify the first function for your needs. Or continue using the second one :)

Comment: @user1585033 Try the updated first version, I added u+06F0-06F9. Or use the updated second function with complete support for all Unicode class Nd : "Number, Decimal Digit".

Comment: I wrote that alert function for a given input by user . for number zero typed by user, the output was 6f0

Comment: If it was `6f0` then it was "EXTENDED ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT" instead of "ARABIC-INDIC". The first function (as it is now) supports both and probably is enough for your application. The second one with complete support for the Unicode Nd class is probably overkill for most applications. Good luck!